# Java Quicksort help understand

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm trying to understand the Quicksort algorithm in java.

I have commented my question below beside the part i'm trying to comprehend.

```
public class Quciksort {

  static void qsort( char items[]) {
    qs(items,0,items.length-1); /*how can this method reference its parameters before the method is defined (below)?*/
  }



  private static void qs(char items[], int left, int right) //
  {
    int i, j;
    char x, y;

    i=left; j=right;
    x=items[(left+right)/2];

    do{
        while((items[i] < x) && (i<right)) i++;
        while((x < items[j]) && (j>left)) j--;

        if(i<=j){
            y=items[i];
            items[i]=items[j];
            items[j]=y;
            i++;j--;
            }
    }while (i<=j);

    if(left<j) qs(items, left, j);
    if(i<right) qs(items, i, right);
  }

}
```

Comment: @Tacocat thanks for the response, and sorry for not being to clear. I'm trying to understand how qsort() can make a call to the method of qs() and give values to its parameters, if qs(char items[], int x, int y) has not been created until after?

Comment: @vefthym oh ok, i just assumed since you could not do something like>               {int r=x+y;  int x, y; } you could not do the same to methods.

Comment: I believe @vefthym has answered your question then ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confusing Java with C, in which, if I remember well after 10+ years since last using it, it is a good practice, or maybe required, to declare a method *before* calling it.

In Java, there is no such requirement. Thus, you can call a method that is implemented at a later point in your code.

About the parameters, I am not sure I got your question correctly, but in your example, you are calling `qs` with the array `items` as the first argument (as it was given to the `qsort` method), with 0 for the value of `left` and the length of the `items` array -1, for `right`.